# Sending a signal to stem closes the socket

Tags: python, networking, tor, stem

This code:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    print('is alive BEFORE ? ')
    print(controller.is_alive())
    try:
        controller.signal(Signal.HEARTBEAT)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print('is alive AFTER ? ')
    print(controller.is_alive())

with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    print('is alive 2 ? ')
    print(controller.is_alive())
```

produces this output:

```
is alive BEFORE ?
True
SIGNAL response contained unrecognized status code: 514
is alive AFTER ?
False
is alive 2 ?
True
```

and no heartbeat is logged. Also if I try to make a request to tor after sending the signal I get: [stem] INFO: Error while receiving a control message (SocketClosed): empty socket content

Tor configuration is:
SocksPort 9050
ControlPort 9051

Comment: There is no evidence of a closed socket here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `514` error means `Authentication required`.

After connecting, the first thing you must do is authenticate:

```
with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    print('is alive BEFORE ? ')
    print(controller.is_alive())
    controller.authenticate()
    ...
```

*Also note, Tor closes the connection afer an authentication failure.*  See the [control spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) section 3.5 for more info.

The first stem example goes into these basics in more detail: https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html